# Why does Capistrano run a command differently

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, whenever, rvm-capistrano

I have been noticing some weird stuff with Capistrano lately. But before I can explain that let me provide some head on from where it is exactly coming from.

As a part of updating my `crontab` on every deployment. I decided to use [`whenever/capistrano`](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration) recipe.

But for some reason(not known to me but I see a [issue](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/554) in github describing the same). Every time I attempt to do so I see following error.

**"database configuration does not specify adapter"**

Important bit. here how the command look like

```
INFO [a558a04a] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2@thrasher do bundle exec whenever --update-crontab thrasher --set environment=production --roles=app,web,db as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [a558a04a] Command: cd /home/deploy/project-scp/thrasher/releases/20160129130817 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2@thrasher do bundle exec whenever --update-crontab thrasher --set environment=production --roles=app,web,db
DEBUG [a558a04a]    scheduling frequent upload job
scheduling daily upload job
DEBUG [a558a04a]    [write] crontab file updated
INFO [a558a04a] Finished in 2.411 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Kindly, take a note of the command.

`~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2@thrasher do bundle exec whenever ...`

Now, in order to solve this problem. I **set** the [whenever_command](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano/v3/tasks/whenever.rake#L35), a capistrano variable to look like this.

`set :whenever_command,["RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:stage)",:bundle,:exec,:whenever]`

And ...

When I ran the capistrano again, I saw this.

```
Running /usr/bin/env RAILS=production bundle exec whenever --update-crontab thrasher --set environment=production --roles=app,web,db as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [b67e3351] Command: cd /home/deploy/project-scp/thrasher/releases/20160129131301 && /usr/bin/env RAILS=production bundle exec whenever --update-crontab thrasher --set environment=production --roles=app,web,db
```

Command Executed was

`/usr/bin/env RAILS=production bundle exec whenever ...`

### Question:

Why did the 2 time the command did not look like this.

`~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.2.2@thrasher do RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec whenever`

### Note:

`Rails 4.0.4`

`Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.5.0)`

`Ruby ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]`

Also using

`capistrano/rvm`

### Update:

In accordance with @will_in_wi answer. To solve the `whenever` issue I also tried doing this.(inside `deploy.rb` file.)

```
namespace :deploy do
   ...
   ...
   before "whenever:update_crontab", "deploy:set_rails_env"

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Placing an environment variable inside the `:whenever_command` is not the right way to do it. Based on the whenever/capistrano code, you should use `:whenever_command_environment_variables`.

Remove your `:whenever_command` and try this instead:

```
set :whenever_command_environment_variables, -> { { :rails_env => fetch(:stage) } }
```

Long answer: you are using capistrano/rvm, which does some magic with Capistrano's "command map" to automatically prefix *certain* commands with `~/.rvm/bin/rvm...`. One of those certain commands is `bundle`, for example. If you change the whenever command to no longer start with `:bundle`, the mapping will no longer work.

Comment: do you have any link for this `capistrano/rvm, which does some magic with Capistrano's "command map"`

Comment: I guess I found it.over [here](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake#L40)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your Capfile, you might need to enable some subset of capistrano/rails. That is what will force RAILS_ENV to be set: https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/set_rails_env.rake

Comment: Why it is the case with `whenever` only all the other stuff work out of box.

Comment: I have update the question mentioning that I just tried the approach you just mentioned.

Comment: Hmm. Then I'm out of ideas. If I had to personally do this, I would end up dropping into Pry and walking through the code to figure out how it works. However, where exactly are you getting the "database configuration does not specify adapter" error?

Comment: @will_in_will from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb#L47)